# How to select the cell with the highest value based on 2 cells

Tags: arrays, sorting, filter, google-sheets-formula, match

I'm trying to make a score sheet for a video tournament, and I can not get figure this out.
For example
column  A is users names
Column b is score
Column C is bonus point

And the formula I need is if user 1 and user 2 have the same scored pick the one that has more bonus.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SORTN(A2:A, 1, 0, B2:B, 0, C2:C, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome that worked just like I need it to. Thank you,